# For loop not processing entire xml script in R

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, processing

I am writing a routine to parse xml files that are system log files to capture the logon and logoff messages. As you can see in my code, there are several check points where I verify that the xml file is being completely read, however, when I print the dataframe, only the first event is captured.

```
LG.df <- read_xml("Syslog.xml")


xml_ns(LG.df)
NS<- xml_children(xml_children(LG.df))


EV<- ""
DT<- ""
AN<- ""
AD<- ""
WSN<- ""
SA<- ""

LogEvents.df<- data.frame(EV, DT, AN, AD, WSN, SA)

print(LG.df)


for (i in sequence(length(NS))) {


DT<- NS[1]
DT<- gsub("<DateTime>","",as.character(DT))
DT<- gsub("</DateTime>","",as.character(DT))
#print(DT)
Pr<- NS[2]
Pr<- gsub("<Priority>","",as.character(Pr))
Pr<- gsub("</Priority>","",as.character(Pr))
#print(Pr)
SH<- NS[3]
SH<- gsub("<Source_Host>","",as.character(SH))
SH<- gsub("</Source_Host>","",as.character(SH))
#print(SH)
MT<- NS[4]
MT<- gsub("<MessageText>","",as.character(MT))
MT<- gsub("</MessageText>","",as.character(MT))
#print(MT)


EV<- str_match(MT, "\\d{4}(?=\\tMicrosoft-Windows-Security-Auditing)")

#print(EV)

AN<- str_match(MT, "(?<=Account Name:\\t\\t).*?(?=\\n)")
SID<- str_match(MT, "(?<=Security ID:\\t\\t).*?(?=\\n)")
AD<- str_match(MT, "(?<=Account Domain:\\t\\t).*?(?=\\n)")
WSN<- str_match(MT, "(?<=Workstation Name:\\t\\t).*?(?=\\n)")
SA<- str_match(MT, "(?<=Source Network Address:\\t\\t).*?(?=\\n)")




if(EV == 4624){(LogEvents.df$EV <-(EV))
  (LogEvents.df$DT<- (DT))
  (LogEvents.df$AN<- (AN))
  (LogEvents.df$AD<- (AD))
  (LogEvents.df$WSN<- (WSN))
  (LogEvents.df$SA<- (SA))


  } else if(EV == 4634){(LogEvents.df$EV <-( EV))}
  (LogEvents.df$DT<- (DT))
  (LogEvents.df$AN<- (AN))
  (LogEvents.df$AD<- (AD))
  (LogEvents.df$WSN<- (WSN))
  (LogEvents.df$SA<- (SA))



}
```

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: If you are processing XML files consider using the xml2 or the xml package.  You will have better success than trying string matching.

Comment: @Dave2e, normally, I would agree, however, the way the syslog dumps the contents, string matching was the only effective tool for extracting the desired patters.

Comment: If there are multiple occurrences, maybe `str_match_all()` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Dave2e, that has no effect. The problem is the way each event is packaged in the xml file. The message text, the fourth child in the stream is a compilation of the entire event, with a bunch of superfluous text thrown in to explain what each event is. Wish I could share a sample, unfortunately it is protected by HIPPA regulations.